# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'current_observation' of undefined

Tags: javascript, api

i want get weather forecast and conditions from wunderground , but when i run the code have error with current_observation , the current_observation in side data json of api .

```
$(document).ready(function($){
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.wunderground.com/api/72df18b7f213607b/conditions/forecast/lang:AR/q/CO/zmw:00000.1.WKQTZ.json",
    dataType : "jsonp",
    success : function(parsed_json) {
        var forecast = parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday']['conditions']['current_observation'];

        for (index in forecast,conditions) {
            var newForecastString = 'Weather forecast for ' + forecast[index]['title'] + ' is ' + forecast[index]['fcttext_metric'];
        var newconditionsString = 'Weather forecast for ' + forecast[index]['title'] + ' is ' + forecast[index]['station_id'];
            var newForecastParagraph = $('<p/>').text(newForecastString);
            $("body").append(newForecastParagraph);
        } 
    }
}); });
```

Comment: `for (index in forecast,conditions) {` Whyt is `,conditions` there? That makes it ignore `forecast` and use `conditions`, which isn't defined in your example.

Comment: in json data we have too object , the forecast and conditions

Comment: @aligassan That's not how JSON works. The top level contains `response`, `current_observation`, and `forecast` keys. And you can't loop over two things at once; it makes no sense.

Comment: Then you need two separate loops. Separating them with a comma doesn't do anything useful right there.

Answer (score 0):

`current_observation` is at the top level, e.g., `parsed_json['current_observation`].

Unrelated, but it might be better to post the JSON than expose your API key.

If you're looking for the conditions, they're not an array anywhere, they're a single string value, found in various places.

Comment: can you give me full  Answer

Comment: @aligassan I did; I told you how to get to the current observation. SO isn't really a "do all my work for me" kind of a place, it's more a "teach a man to fish" place, at least for me. Just look at the JSON--that's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

its because`parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday']` does not have `conditions` in it. So `parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday']['conditions']` will be undefined and you are asking for `current_observation` on top of undefined.

```
 "forecast":{
   "txt_forecast": {
    "date":"6:28 PM AST",
    "forecastday": [{
    "period":0,
    "icon":"clear",
    "icon_url":"http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/clear.gif",
    "title":"السبت",
    "fcttext":"صافٍ غالبًا. درجة الحرارة الصغرى 81 درجة فهرنهيت.",
    "fcttext_metric":"صافٍ غالبًا. درجة الحرارة الصغرى 27 درجة مئوية.",
    "pop":"0"
    }]
   }
}
```